# how to replace a date which is in my file with Current date in shell script and send that in subject of the mail

Tags: shell, unix

Hi i tried this and want to enhance the below script to send mail with current date as subject and also want to Replace a date which is already in my out.txt with current date
(TodayDate)07/30/2012(/TodayDate) my tag will be like this and want to replace it with current date

```
grep -i "<returnMessage>" out.txt |mailx -s " we are fine on $date" xyz@yahoo.com
```

Comment: able to get subject with current date "we are fine on $(date) its working fine

Comment: can you show the content of out.txt in block letters.I'm get confused with your content.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using sed.
Create a sh file, say temp.sh having the following content -

```
CURR_DT=`date +"%m/%d/%Y"`
echo `sed "s;..\/..\/....;$CURR_DT;g" out.txt`
```

Now, run the following command -

```
sh temp.sh | mail -s `date +"%m/%d/%Y"` xyz@yahoo.com
```

Although, it doesn't make use of the (TodayDate) tag.

Comment: grep -i "" out.txt |mailx -s " we are fine on $(date)" xyz@yahoo.com

Comment: What i need now is how to change the date which is in between Todaydate tag with current date which is in my file out.txt

Comment: If you just want to replace date in the text, you can use the sed part of my solution(temp.sh). Are you facing any issues with my solution? Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Insert

```
sed "s,(TodayDate)../../....(/TodayDate),`date +%m/%d/%Y`," |
```

before `mailx`.